NGINX redirect dynamic page to another website
I am trying to redirect ONE dynamic page to another website using an NGINX directive:
"/course/view.php?id=24" TO "www.example.com/dir/dir"
I have tried both of the following. While NGINX accepts them, they do not work. Suggestions?
location /course/view.php?id=24 {
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com/dir/dir;
}


location /course/view.php {
    rewrite /course/view.php?id=24 www.example.com/dir/dir break;
}

Thx

You cannot use the query string (anything from the ? and after) in a location expression or a rewrite regex. It has already be removed from the optimised URI and placed in the $args variable.
You can test the entire requested URI using the $request_uri variable.
For example:
if ($request_uri = "/course/view.php?id=24") {
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com/dir/dir;
}


Weirdly, that causes the download of view.php, but only for the inside URI. So the front half is good, just can't pass on the outside URI.
